# Set Grid's IsMouseOver to True in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a style with a Trigger for `IsMouseOver`, and I want to trigger that Trigger (heh) from C#. How can this be done? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `DataTrigger` and then bind to a property in your ViewModel.

First create a `bool` property that will advise the View whether it should 'show' or 'not show' your style.

```
public bool GridTrigger
{
    get { return this.gridTrigger; }
    set { // raise a PropertyChange event, as per normal
}
```

And then add the `DataTrigger` to the XAML

```
<Grid.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GridTrigger}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource MyMouseOverStyle"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Grid.Triggers>
```

This obviously assumes you are using MVVM!

Comment: What if I have multiple elements I need to trigger this way...? Especially if they're dynamically created.

Comment: Oh, and how do I raise a "PropertyChange" event?

Comment: If they're all `Grid` elements then include this as part of an unnamed `Grid` style for your UserControl, and it will apply. If you're doing it code behind, just create a DataTrigger and add it to the created UserControls.

Comment: @NeXXeuS Are you using MVVM? If so, your ViewModel must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and you probably have a method called `PropertyChanged(string propertyName)` that you need to call when you change the value of a property...

Comment: I'm not sure what MVVM is - I'm a relatively new WPF developer.

Comment: @NeXXeuS Model-View-ViewModel. If you're not sure whether you're using MVVM then I hazard a guess that triggering custom styles will be a challenge for you.  Try reading [MVVM Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4959/discussion-between-nexxeus-and-kirk-broadhurst)